# primefaces datatable reflow in desktop browser

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

primefaces 5.2

i have a primefaces datatable, the table is very long which is why i want to show it in column stacked mode, i tried using reflow attribute of the datatable.

now if i use the developers mode in chrome and switch to mobile view when i reduce the size of the screen it does in fact behave responsive and goes into stacked column mode, now i want to show that type of table in normal desktop view as well. i thought simple things like just reducing the size of the table would help but no matter how small i reduce the size it just crams the table into that tiny space instead of making it responsive.

am i missing something about how to make something behave responsive on a desktop browser.

```
<p:dataTable id="tb1" var="ths" value="#{thb.sitetracking}"
            rowIndexVar="rowindex"  reflow="true" 
            >
```

in normal size the table looks like this

[image]

in chrome developers mode mobile view

[image]

if i resize the table to get the same effect, instead of a responsive size change this happens

```
<p:dataTable id="tb1" var="ths" value="#{thb.sitetracking}"
            rowIndexVar="rowindex"  reflow="true"  style="width:200px"
            >
```

[image]

if i resize my browser with same table above and make it smaller, it works

[image]

maybe i am just not understanding what responsive actually means, is it not possible to trigger a responsive behaviour by changing the size of the table, it seems to only work when the size of the browser changes

My main objective of doing this doesn't really have much to do with making the table responsive the real thing that i want to achieve is getting the table into column stacked mode and from what i have seen this is the only way PF does it

any help would be appreciated

Comment: In one case you set an explicit width, in one case you don't. Might make a huge difference, unrelated to developer mode or not

Comment: @Kukeltje in the first case i am showing the table in its normal size, in the third one i have set the width because i want the table to do what it does in developers mode, i want it to behave responsive and go into column stacked mode

Comment: Setting the width from CSS does not do that. Resize your browser to achieve the objective. Nothing PF related, plain css media-querie things

Comment: This is exactely how it is supposed to work... Situation Normal, just not what you expected. Indeed a good thing to learn some basics about responsiveness

Comment: @Kukeltje My main objective of this whole thing doesnt really have much with the table being responsive, what i really just wanted was to get the table into column stacked mode and this seemed like the only way PF allows it

Comment: Then use a datalist/grid/...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflow mode works with CSS media query. When your window width is less than 35em (see also the primefaces.css snippet below) then reflow mode is applied.

Thus, applying a `width: 200px;` to your `dataTable` isn't taken into account and will not result in a stacked datatable.

To achieve your goal (applying stack mode when your window width is larger than 35em) you could create (I can't figure out a cleaner solution) your own css class which got rid of the media query. Something like **table-reflow-desktop**:

```
.table-reflow-desktop .ui-datatable-data td .ui-column-title {
      display: none;
}
.table-reflow-desktop thead th,
.table-reflow-desktop tfoot td {
      display: none;
}
.table-reflow-desktop .ui-datatable-data td {
     text-align: left;
     display: block;
     border: 0px none;
     width: 100%;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     float: left;
     clear: left;
}
.table-reflow-desktop .ui-datatable-data.ui-widget-content {
     border: 0px none;
}
.table-reflow-desktop .ui-datatable-data tr.ui-widget-content {
     border-left: 0px none;
     border-right: 0px none;
}
.table-reflow-desktop .ui-datatable-data td .ui-column-title {
     padding: .4em;
     min-width: 30%;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: -.4em 1em -.4em -.4em;
}
```

And don't forget to apply this class to your `p:dataTable`:

```
<p:dataTable id="tb1" var="ths" value="#{thb.sitetracking}" rowIndexVar="rowindex" styleClass="table-reflow-desktop">
```

For reference, here is the original PrimeFaces 5.2 css part which is responsible of the reflow mode:

```
/** Reflow **/
.ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data td .ui-column-title {
   display: none;
}
@media ( max-width: 35em) {
    .ui-datatable-reflow thead th,
    .ui-datatable-reflow tfoot td {
        display: none;
    }
    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data td {
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
        border: 0px none;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }
    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data.ui-widget-content {
        border: 0px none;
    }
    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data tr.ui-widget-content {
        border-left: 0px none;
        border-right: 0px none;
    }
    .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data td .ui-column-title {
        padding: .4em;
        min-width: 30%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: -.4em 1em -.4em -.4em;
    }
}
```